# Best way to run a Perl script from weblogic Java EE application

Tags: java, perl, weblogic, exec, solaris

I currently work in a Weblogic Java EE project, where from time to time the application executes a Perl script to do some batch jobs. In the application the script is getting invoked as

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmdString);
```

Though it is a dangerous way to run, but it was working properly until we had a requirement to execute the script synchronously under a for loop. After a couple of run we are getting 
`java.io.IOException: Not enough space` as probably OS is running out of virtual memory while exec-ing under a for loop. As a result we are not able to run the script at all in the server.

I am desperately looking for a safer and better way to run the Perl script, where we don't need to fork the parent process, or at-least not to eat-up all swap space!

The spec is as follows:

```
Appserver - Weblogic 9.52  
JDK - 1.5   
OS - SunOS 5.10 
Sun-Fire-T200
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to keep your code unchanged and have enough disk free space, you can just add a sufficiently large swap area to your OS.

Assuming you need 10 GB, here is how you do it with UFS:

```
mkfile 10g /export/home/10g-swap
swap -a /export/home/10g-swap
echo "/export/home/10g-swap - - swap - no -" >> /etc/vfstab
```

If you use ZFS, that would be:

```
zfs create -V 10gb rpool/swap1
swap -a /dev/zvol/dsk/rpool/swap1
```

Don't worry about that large a swap, this won't have any performance impact as the swap will only be used for virtual memory reservation, not pagination.

Otherwise, as already suggested in previous replies, one way to avoid the virtual memory issue you experience would be to use a helper program, i.e. a small service that your contact through a network socket (or a higher level protocol like ssh) and that executes the perl script "remotely".

Note that the issue has nothing to do with a 32-bit or 64-bit JVM, it is just Solaris doesn't overcommit memory and this is by design.

Answer (score 1):

I've had something similar on a couple of occasions. Since the child process is a fork of the (very large parent it can see all of it shares all it's memory (using copy on write). What i discovered was that the kernel needs to be able to ensure that it could copy all of the memory pages before forking the child, on a 32bit OS you run out of virtual head run really fast.

Possible solutions:

- Use a 64Bit OS and JVM, pushes the issue down the road so far it doesn't matter
- Host your script in another process (like HTTPD) and poke it using a HTTP request to invoke it

Comment: Your first solution won't work as is. There is no 32-bit Solaris 10 for SPARC anyway and whether the JVM is 32 or 64 bit wouldn't make any difference.

Comment: It has to be said my experience was with linux, and it made all the difference, a 64-bit kernel should always be able to fork as all it needs is enough virtual address space.

Comment: Linux over-commits memory so indeed, switching to a 64-bit kernel would allow almost unlimited memory reservation on this OS. This doesn't apply to Solaris. A 64 bit kernel is what Anindya is running and the issue is there. On Solaris a 64-bit JVM would actually make the problem worse as its footprint would be larger.

Answer (score 1):

Create a perl-server, which reads perl scripts via network and executes them one by one.